# Ruby on rails error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Can someone take a look at this?

An error occured while installing nokogiri (1.5.2), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install nokogiri -v '1.5.2'` succeeds before bundling.

Comment: What happened when you tried what they suggest?

Comment: @Mischa nothing! still does not work! :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this tutorial :----- http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html